# MultiBinding(WPF) alternative for Windows Store Apps

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am developing a Windows Store App which displays fields of specific types throughout the App and allows the user to change their preference of units for display of that type of field.

Using an example of fields related to Heights, if using MultiBinding from WPF (not available in WinRT) I would want to do something like this:

```
<Page x:Name="Page" ...>

...

    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource HeightConverter}>
                <Binding Path="HeightInMetres"/>
                <Binding Path="HeightDisplayUnit" ElementName="Page"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>

    </TextBlock>

....

</Page>
```

Where HeightUnit would be an enumeration for say feet, metres..

The HeightDisplayUnit and HeightInMetres are held in separate view-models.

In the example above the HeightDisplayUnit is a property of a the Page class and the HeightInMetres being a property of a view-model of type Person which is bound throughout including for example in DataTemplates used in ListViews.  There is a single instance of the view-model containing HeightDisplayUnit but many instances of the Person view-model.

In various spots in the App I may have binding to person where I want to use the 
Can anyone think of a way to achieve the aim of triggering an update to all the "height" fields when either the Page property *HeightDisplayUnit* or the *HeightInMetres* property of the Person view-model is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that the data your are binding are coming from different view models and it could be too complicated to merge them into a single property, you should consider creating a custom control to handle this scenario.

While you will still not be able to multi-bind, you will be able to expose two DependencyProperties to handle the bindings.

Comment: I've gone with a custom control with 2 dependency properties and a value converter input.  I like the solution as it solves the problem in a general way and applies to the case where the formatted value are not even remotely in the same format.  Thanks to all that responded.

Answer (score 2):

It's straightforward to add another read-only property in the view-model.  Just remember to raise "PropertyChanged" from each of the other properties.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding FormattedHeight}" />
```

...

```
public string FormattedHeight
{
    get { return string.Format("{0} {1}", HeightInMetres, HeightDisplayUnit); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The issue is that the HeightDisplayUnit is not a property of the same view-model as the HeightInMetres.  See edits for further details.

Comment: @alistairm I think both the new answers here are good suggestions that should work.

Answer (score 2):

There are NuGet packages that provide MultiBinding functionality for [Windows Store](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRT-Multibinding-Windows/) apps. You can find documentation [here](https://github.com/Verbon/WinRTMultiBinding).

Answer (score 1):

you could add multiple Runs to 1 textblock and bind both of them to different sources:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="String1">AAA</x:String>
    <x:String x:Key="String2">BBB</x:String>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBlock>
        <Run Text="{StaticResource String1}"></Run>
        <Run Text="{StaticResource String2}"></Run>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is a very good suggestion. Much simpler than mine if you do not need to control the order in which the data appears.